# Installing pathogen inside .dotfiles

Tags: plugin-pathogen

I want to install my vim plugins in `~/.dotfiles/vim`

What is the proper way to install Pathogen in this case and keep it under version control?

What I've tried is to install it in `~/.dotfiles/vim/autoload/pathogen.vim` and create a symbolic link to this in `~./vim/autoload`

But this way i would have to create symbolic links to all of my plugins, and pathogen itself is not under version control.

How do i do this correctly?

Comment: You could simply copy the file to `~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim` and have `~/.vim/autoload` in your version control. Then you can manually update pathogen once in a while. Since this is not often updated I don't think it is really a problem not to always have the last version, you could only update it when you detect a bug and the bug is fixed by a new commit. Otherwise you'll probably have to install it as a git submodule (see doc [here](https://github.com/blog/2104-working-with-submodules)).

Comment: @statox Ok I'm convinced that it's not worth the trouble to keep pathogen in a submodule. But I have all my other plugins in submodules.
My setup so far is as follows:

Pathogen installed inside `~/.dotfiles/vim/autoload/`

A symbolic link for Pathogen is inside `~/.vim/autoload/`

Plugins as submodules inside `~/.dotfiles/vim/bundle/`

But the plugins are not recognized unless i manually create symbolic links for them like i did for pathogen.

Comment: Look at the first question of the [pathogen FAQ](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen#faq): Tim Pope provides a way to keep pathogen as a submodule. Now I'm not sure why all of your plugins are in submodule: if you have pathogen it is possible not to put the plugin in the version control. This way on a fresh install you use pathogen to install them and you use pathogen once in a while to update them, it what plugin managers are for, right? (I'm assuming pathogen works more or less like Vundle or Vim-plug because I never used pathogen)

Comment: @statox Pathogen doesn't update the plugins. That's why i keep each plugin in a submodule :)

Comment: Oh right. Well I'm not the best to answer your question then :) (The best I could do would be to advise you to use Vim-plug which is way easier to use IMO but that's not really what I would call an interesting answer)

Comment: I have such setup. I have all my plugins (including Pathogen) in `~/.vim/bundle`. They are submodules, and `~/.vim` is a simlink to `~/.dotfiles/vim`. In there there is also `autoload` folder with symlink to `pathogen.vim` from `bundle/vim-pathogen`. The point is that whole `~/.vim` is under version control of `~/.dotfiles` and it works exactly as it would be in `~/.vim` as a normal directory.

Comment: @grodzik I think you ment to say the plugins are in `~/.dotfiles/vim/bundle`  ?
It worked. Thank you very much ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup whole Vim directory inside `~/.dotfiles/vim` and do a symlink

```
~/.vim -> ~/.dotfiles/vim
```

This way you will have all the plugins as submodules (including Pathogen) inside `~/.dotfiles/vim/bundle`. To handle Pathogen, create a link

```
~/.dotfiles/vim/autoload/pathogen.vim -> ~/.dotfiles/vim/bundle/<path to pathogen.vim>
```